# Capture http json body response and convert into array in angular ionic5

Tags: arrays, json, angular, type-conversion, converters

I am stuck and while looking around here and other pages I could not find something that fits :/
What I want is to extract it and having it in a manner that I can use to build a simple table in html to look like

| response | count |
| --- | --- |
| [value] | [value] |
| [value] | [value] |

and also to have it in list format to then use later in chart.js but that will be later.

(FYI I am not a dev person, learning along the way - but I am good at lego :) so linking bricks and adapting is what I do to learn coding so apologies if beginner questions :) )

So, I have an http call (GET) working. it returns body:

```
[
  {
    "response": "Yes",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "response": "No",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

but I can't figure out how to use that...

My http service query:

```
getPollResults(pollId): Observable<Pollresults>{
      return this.http
      .get<Pollresults>(this.base_path + '/polls/responses/' + pollId)
      .pipe(
        retry(2),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
```

my model for Pollresults:

```
export class Pollresults {

    response: string;
    count: number;

}
```

my component page.ts call which seems to capture the data but then I am stuck on how the hell to use it...

```
 export class PollResultsPage implements OnInit {

   uid: string;
   dataPollresults: Pollresults;

   constructor(
     private httpConfigService: HttpConfigService
   ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      // this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];
      this.uid = "alphapoll";
      //get item details using id
      this.httpConfigService.getPollResults(this.uid).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.dataPollresults = response;
      //data => resolve(Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]))
         })
   }
```

any help on how to properly extract and get an array? and how to add it in the html?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
getPollResults(pollId): Observable<Pollresults>{
  return this.http
  .get<Pollresults>(this.base_path + '/polls/responses/' + pollId)
  .pipe(
    retry(2),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
```

}

To this

```
getPollResults(pollId): Observable<Pollresults[]>{
  return this.http
  .get<Pollresults>(this.base_path + '/polls/responses/' + pollId)
  .pipe(
    retry(2),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
```

}